# Why does a simple coroot $\alpha^{(i)}$ correspond to a Cartan subalgebra element $H^i$?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I read [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=B_JQryjNYyAC&pg=PA93&lpg=PA93&dq=roots%20and%20weight%20lattices%20the%20dynkin%20basis&source=bl&ots=Xsv_eP66w6&sig=6A37nbY71AOxpCqdUnKr0e1NVrE&hl=de&sa=X&ei=5dRJVf2GNoPWaqWwgYAP&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=roots%20and%20weight%20lattices%20the%20dynkin%20basis&f=false) that a simple coroot $\alpha^{(i)}$ corresponds to a Cartan subalgebra element $H^i$ **and don't understand why this should be the case**.

Roots are the weights of the adjoint representation:

$$ [H_i , E_\alpha] = \alpha_i E_\alpha$$

where $H_i$ are the Cartan generators and $E_\alpha$ the other generators, i.e. the eigenvectors of the Cartan generators in the adjoint representation.

For another eigenvector we have, of course

$$ [H_i , E_{\alpha^{(2)}}] = \alpha_i^{(2)} E_{\alpha^{(2)}}$$

Therefore the superscript denotes the different roots and the subscript the corresponding components.

Each root $\alpha^{(k)}$ therefore corresponds to a non-Cartan generator. The simple roots are a linearly independent subset of the roots that can be used as a basis for the root space. For simplicity, let's assume we are dealing only with simply laced algebras, which means the roots are self-dual. Therefore the coroots coincide with the roots.

**How does this fit together with the statement above that each simple coroot corresponds to a Cartan generator?**